# How to draw Tilted Rectangle in Html 5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Let say I have x, y, width and height. I need to draw a inclined/tilted Rectangle at particular angle. I cannot use context.rotate. Because it is changing other shapes of canvas.

Comment: http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html

Comment: Can you please show me the code?

Comment: You can see the code by viewing the source of the page (HTML) along with the linked [jsgl.js](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/jsgl.js) file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `context.rotate`, you just have to undo the rotation before you draw the other shapes.  [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/NVUSW/):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
context.rect(88, 50, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

context.rotate(0.5);
context.beginPath();
context.rect(138, 120, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = "#FE8E9D";
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

context.rotate(-0.5);
context.beginPath();
context.rect(188, 190, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = "#FEEF8E";
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have lot of objects in place in canvas. i cannot change this. I just need to rotate a rectangle. context.rotate is disturbing all the objects in canvas

Comment: I know how canvas works. But I need the new co-ordinates of tilted recangle.

Comment: I am checking this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432561/rotate-point-in-rectangle

Comment: A more better, http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/h/graham1.html Whet do you think?

Comment: @user960567 I think if these links are indicating solutions to your problem, then your problem isn't what your question is indicating.

Comment: With avilable co-ordinates I can easily draw a tilted rectangle